# Que son los tipos de datos abstractos

Tags: poo

Que tal comunidad, como pueden observar soy nuevo en esto de la programación, estoy comenzando por la lógica de programación alguien podría explicarme de una manera breve o sencilla cuales  son y como se ejecutan los tipos de datos abstractos

Answer (score 0):

Son clases Padre donde se consideran métodos que aún no se conoce su desarrollo.
Recién se conocerá en alguna clase Hija. A estos métodos se les conoce como
métodos abstractos y utilizan la palabra reservada **abstract** para su identificación.

Cuando una Clase Padre contiene por lo menos un método abstracto se le conoce
como *Clase Abstracta* y también debe estar precedía por la palabra reservada
**abstract**.

Estas clases pueden tener además métodos no abstractos que invoquen a métodos
abstractos si lo necesitan para definir un comportamiento. Sin embargo, no se puede instanciar objetos invocando al constructor de la clase base abstracta.

Las clases Hija deben desarrollar todos los métodos abstractos de la clase Padre. Además, la clase Hija puede redefinir cualquier método de la clase Padre, con el mismo nombre. Incluso pueden utilizar la palabra reservada ***super*** para referirse a cualquier método del mismo nombre que esté definido en la clase Padre.

En el funcionamiento del polimorfismo se puede identificar el concepto de “enlace tardío” que consiste en que recién se conocerá el método a ejecutar en el momento de la ejecución, más no en la compilación.

Comment: Esa palabra reservada para que lenguaje de programacion esta referida